# I/O interception in KVM

Tags: io, kvm

I'm working on the interception of disk I/O on KVM(Kernal-based virtual machine). The aim is to get the block number that the Virtual Machine is being read/written, and to interrupt this operation(if this block the user would not like to read/write).

The operations that directly write to disk could be interrupted, but modifications by vim, we could still see, but after restarting the virtual machine, the modifications will be canceled (which means after restarting VM, the modifications will not be affected, perhaps it's called buffered IO?).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I tried especially on EXT2 filesystem, and is there a general solution for all the EXT filesystems?

Thank you!